# Who's been in my /opt/lib dotfiles?

Tags: compiling, shared-library

Long story short, I recently decided to compile blender from source for the second time in a year. Not sure if I took this long at it last year. As usual, it all comes down to the libraries being in the right place and up-to-date with each other.

So, hunting for a bug in my libraries, I realized something was giving `cmake` the wrong information. And then I noticed, my Python installation (the most important part of compiling Blender) wasn't matching the `CMakeCache.txt` -- so I went straight to `/opt/lib`, to find out what was happening.

There was no Python library in `/opt/lib` -- not that I totally expected to find one, since I don't use those folders for shared library files. But what I found surprised me.

```
meglet@meglet-Alienware-13:/opt/lib$ ls -a
.                                  .oiio-2.2.15.1-magiccheck-18-true
..                                 .openexr-2.5.5-magiccheck-15-true
.alembic-1.7.12-magiccheck-2-true  .openvdb-7.0.0-magiccheck-1-true
.alembic-1.7.16-magiccheck-2-true  .openvdb-8.0.1-magiccheck-2-true
.blosc-1.5.0-magiccheck-0-true     .osd-3.4.3-magiccheck-2-true
.boost-1.73.0-magiccheck-14-true   .osl-1.10.9-magiccheck-21-true
.llvm-12.0.0-magiccheck-3-true     .osl-1.11.14.1-magiccheck-21-true
.numpy-1.10.1-magiccheck-0-false   .osl-1.11.17.0-magiccheck-21-true
.ocio-1.0.9-magiccheck-2-false     .python-3.10.2-magiccheck-3-true
.ocio-1.1.0-magiccheck-2-true      .python-3.5.3-magiccheck-1-false
.ocio-2.0.0-magiccheck-3-true      .usd-20.05-magiccheck-1-true
.oiio-1.8.13-magiccheck-17-true    .xr-openxr-1.0.8-magiccheck-2-true
```

I wasn't able to find any reference to these so-called magic checks. I'm not sure the program responsible for this exists anymore or is used by anyone. But still, I'd like to know.

Comment: what's the create/modified/access times of those files

Comment: @JaromandaX I deleted them once I asked this question. I should have posted my `ls -l` output. I have no way of knowing.